# My textbox isn't visible

Tags: asp.net, events

So i am trying to assign a text to a variable when TextChanged event is triggered. This is my code :

```
...
TextBox textbox = new TextBox(); 
textbox.TextChanged += textbox_TextChanged;
...

    void textbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        value = textbox.Text;
    }
```

The problem is that inside the event code block, the textbox isn't seen. It appears the following error : "The name 'textbox' does not appear in the current context" . 
What should i do to see it inside the event code block ?

Comment: What about using `sender` parameter of your event handler, it should be the same `TextBox` object.

Comment: I hope you are trying correctly like `value = ((TextBox)sender).Text;`

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a dynamic textbox it won't be referenced in your designer file. You'll need to store it as a property in your code behind class.

```
// OnLoad
this.MyTextbox = new TextBox(); 
this.MyTextbox .TextChanged += textbox_TextChanged;

// event
void textbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    value = this.MyTextbox .Text;
}
```